# VBScript /w AppActivate for multiple instances of an application

Tags: vbscript

We have an application that will minimize itself to the top-left corner of the screen when you disconnect from your VMware View desktop. So I wrote the following VBS that will activate the app and maximize it that works fine.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 objShell.AppActivate "notepad"

objShell.SendKeys "% r"

objShell.SendKeys "% x"
```

But some users have multiple instances of the same app open. So I'm wondering how to get this script to execute for every instance of the application? I'm assuming I'll have to key off of the PID, since each instance will have its own PID, but I'm unsure how to do this.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppActivate accepts a PID. You could use the WMI to retrieve the PIDs of all processes with that name.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Shell, WMI, wql, process

Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

wql = "SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'notepad.exe'"

For Each process In WMI.ExecQuery(wql)
    Shell.AppActivate process.ProcessId
    Shell.SendKeys "% r"
    Shell.SendKeys "% x"
Next
```

Also see [the `Win32_Process class` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Interesting, it works, but only for one of the instances of Notepad. BUT, if I remark out the 2nd to last command (Shell.SendKeys "% r" (which does a Restore)), it actually maximizes both. Which is fine for my notepad test. But the actual app I need to do this for requires the Restore first, then the Maximize command. If you just do the Maximize command, it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Dang {enter} key! Any ideas why yours works for one but not the other, yet removing the R command will then work for both? Is it timing? Maybe some sort of wait statement before it loops??

Comment: Could be. Try `WScript.Sleep(100)`

Comment: BINGO! I just did the sleep after the SekdKeys X, and it worked fine! Thought I might of had to insert them throughout, but I guess that makes sense since it worked for one not the other. So it wasn't the process, it was just the time before it started the next loop. Going to test this today with the actual app (not Notepad) and see how I make out. But should be OK. Will give you credit once it's working, which I assume it will. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a champ! Although I had to put in a Sleep command after the AppActivate as well as the SendKeys. Thank you very much!